# TextView dentro de FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

al declarar un FirebaseListAdapter se puede usar una vista para mostrar los
datos dentro del ListView al cual se le setea el adaptador. Pero al colocar un TextView por ejemplo aquí.

```
    Firebase cursosRef = rootRef.child("NRC");  
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapterFire = new   FirebaseListAdapter<String>  (this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursosRef) {  
        @Override  
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {  
            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);  
            text.setText(s);  
        }  
    };  
}
```

El layout que va dentro de los parametros del findViewById...¿En que parte del XML debo crearlo?

Comment: El layout que contiene tu TexView se carga en onCreate() y  findViewById es para buscar una referencia de algún elemento dentro de este.Ve mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

¿Dónde quieres colocar exactamente el TextView? ¿Dentro del adaptador para cargar un ListView o un GridView?

Si es así tendrás que crear tu adaptador personalizado extendiendo de la clase de Firebase y asignarle un layout personalizado en el que incluirás tú TextView.

Si quieres un ejemplo o orientación, este repositorio de GitHub te será de mucha ayuda:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

Es similar a una Activity, se realiza dentro del método `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
...
```

Aquí es donde asignas el layout que contendrá tus elementos, en este caso tu `TextView.`